# Postgres date_trunc function with timezone

Tags: c#, postgresql, pgadmin, postgres-11

Im using a C# query that automatically uses the date_trunc with timezone function, however when trying to run the function in postgres it doesnt work. I receive this error:

```
ERROR:  function date_trunc(unknown, timestamp with time zone, unknown) does not exist
```

According to the Postgres [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC). It should support:

```
date_trunc(field, source [, time_zone ])
```

For example I can call,

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2001-02-16 20:38:40+00');
```

But not,

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2001-02-16 20:38:40+00', 'Australia/Sydney');
```

Is this optional time_zone field new and my postgres out of date? Currently running version PostgreSQL 11.14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying the time zone in `date_trunc` is not supported in [Postgresql 11](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC).

Take a look at `AT TIME ZONE` described just below `date_trunc` in the link above, you could use something like

```
date_trunc('day', TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40+00' AT TIME ZONE 'Australia/Sydney')
```

HTH

Comment: That would make sense on why im receiving this error, its weird that my code is generating a query that my current postgres version doesnt support.